# Cell range issue to create a chart using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell `Range(A2:C12)` for creating charts. And using,

```
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C12")
```

... code in VBA to create line chart.

But I need that instead of  providing cell `Range("A2:C12")` in vba, i want to define my cell range in excel itself. For e.g., in cell `A14`, I will type `A2:C12`. Finally Vba must fetch the data from cell `a14`.

Comment: @Jeeped Why did you delete your answer?  I was about to post exactly the same thing, and then noticed your deleted answer.  So now I am intrigued as to what was wrong with it.

Comment: @YowE3K - Nothing. I've taken an attitude where I will answer a beginner question but will leave something that the OP has to discover for themselves. I believe that it is only in this way that I can obstruct the help vampires and still help people that truly wish to improve their skills. I did not appreciate the comment attached to my solution so I deleted my response.

Comment: @Jeeped I had a bit of a chuckle at that comment - I thought the difference was fairly obvious :D  (Even though the writer had no VBA reputation, they should have been able to see the change from a string literal `"A2:C12"` to a sheet reference of `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").Text`!)

Comment: @Jeeped Anyway, if you undelete the answer, I will upvote it.  (I could hardly do otherwise if it is almost word for word what I would have written!)

Comment: @YowE3K - **Exactly**... but by explaining it would have eliminated the need for the OP to actually understand it by themself and **that** is how we learn programming.

Comment: @YowE3K - Go ahead and post your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cell reference's value just as easily as a string literal:

```
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").Text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time and answer. I appreciate your help on this. :-)